# IPCZQ cookie httpOnly

Tags: java, security, tomcat, cookies, https

I have to set httpOnly flags to all the cookies that my server sends. My scenario is:

1. Login using an independent web-login (I can't access the code).
2. If successs -> redirect to my webApp.

I have successfully setted the httpOnly flag to all the cookies that my server sends (like JSESSIONID). But there are two strangers cookies (IPCZQX... and HASH_IPCZQX...) that do not get set up and I don't know where they come from.

Tracing the login requests, I get:

1. https://...login.../
2. https://myApp:443/    -> Here appears these stranges IPCZQX... cookies
3. https://myApp:443/app -> Initial point of my webApp, here JSESSIONID is sent

I am using Tomcat, and I have configured the context to use httpOnly.

What is that strange cookie and how can I set it up?

Answer (score 2):

Those are cookies set by Novell/NetIQ Access Manager. I don't think you have to worry much about them, or maybe you can tweak Access Manager settings (I don't know the product to that detail).

Comment: But, why my app server (tomcat) is sending that cookies without the httpOnly flag? 
Thanks you, I didn't know about that AM.

Comment: I mean,  what I understand is: NetIQ AM validate login and redirect to my app (send that cookies without security flags to my server in the '/' context), then my server responds and return that cookies without httpOnly flag active (why?), and then it go to my '/app' context and set the remaining cookies well. Is '/' context like a proxy/redirect location?

Comment: Looks like NetIQ AM proxies all requests to your app.   Contact your administrator to configure AM to forward Secure cookies flag and HttpOnly flags if it is not done already.